# Print last matching line

Tags: bash, sed

Using `sed`, I would like to print the last matching line of a file. I came across

[sed: return last occurrence match until end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7724778)

however, I would like only the matching line itself, not any range of lines. Using that page I actually came up with a working command

```
$ sed '/out_time=/h; $!d; x' progress.txt
out_time=00:00:07.720000
```

The question is why does this work, or to put another way what is going on in this command. Also include a simpler `sed` command, if one exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, these are three independent commands run on each line (cycle):

- the `h` command replaces the current hold buffer with each line containing `out_time=`.
- the `$!d` deletes any line that isn't the last and restarts the next cycle.
- the `x` command swaps the hold and pattern buffers.

The effect is that the final `out_time=` line is placed in the hold buffer, and the only line that escapes through the `$!d` filter (the last line of the file) is swapped with that hold buffer before printing.

Think of it as a program along the following lines:

```
for every line in file:
    if line contains "out_time=":
        holdbuff = line
    if line is not last line of file:
        continue for loop
    swap line and holdbuff
    print line
```

Of course, the whole tortured process can be avoided if you have the *right* tools for the job:

```
grep 'out_time=' progress.txt | tail -1
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this may be considered simpler:

```
sed -n '/out_time=/h; ${x;p;}' progress.txt
```

which may also be written:

```
sed -n '/out_time=/h; $x; $p' progress.txt
```

In all of these, `sed` is just holding a matching line in the hold space, so the last match it finds is in the hold space when it gets to the end of the file.  At that point, it pulls the hold space into the pattern space and then prints it.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer *without* any pipes using `awk` (someone mentioned correct tools...):

```
awk '/out_time=/{last=$0} END{print last}'  progress.txt
```

Explanation:

- `/$PAT/{...}`: save the matched occurance to variable `last`, overwriting the previous occurance
- `END{...}` : execute block whe exiting the program, in this case printing the value of `last`