# How could I reorder the includes in C header files?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a number of .cpp and .hpp files which contain an #include "my.hpp" which I want to move it in each file to be the last of the includes like this:

current:

```
#include "my.hpp"
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "bar.hpp"
```

or

```
#include "whatever.hpp"
#include "my.hpp"
#include "bar.hpp"
```

needed:

```
#include "whatever.hpp"
#include "something.hpp"
#include "my.hpp"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go with find and perl:

```
find . -name "*.?pp" -exec perl -0777 -pi -e 's/(#include "my.hpp"\n)((#include .*\n)*)/$2$1/g' {} \;
```

e: forgot to add -0777 (multiple lines enabled)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to work out a complete script, but here's an idea:

1. Run `grep` to find only the files containing `#include "my.hpp"` and run the following stages only on these files
2. Cut the problematic include line using something like `sed 's/#include "my.hpp"'//`
3. Find the last include line using `tac` and `sed` and append to it your include line - See [this question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724778/sed-return-last-occurrence-match-until-end-of-file) for details. I'm guessing something like

   `tac | sed 's/^\(#include .*\)$/\1\n#include "my.hpp"/q' | tac`

Details may depend on your exact files, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rsi '/^#include\b/!b;:a;/#include\b[^\n]*$/{$bb;N;ba};:b;s/(#include my.hpp"\n)(.*)(#include\b[^\n]*\n)/\3\2\1/' file1 file2 filen
```

This assumes the `#includes` are consecutive and are not the last entries in the file.