# search for the last occurence of a string in a file and append to it

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, append

I have a file containing commands like these:

```
doadoodle <parameters> 
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
```

What I want to do is find the LAST occurrence of "doadoodle" and after that I want to append the following line:

```
 "rc=\$?
echo \"\$rc  is return code of last doadoodle \" 
 exit \$rc "
```

The net result will look like this:

```
doadoodle <parameters> 
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>

rc=$?
echo "$rc  is return code of last doadoodle" 
exit $rc

wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
```

I wrote this as if `echo` were to write to the file and all ambiguous characters had to be escaped.

```
 "rc=\$?
echo \"\$rc  is return code of last doadoodle \" 
 exit \$rc "
```

I tried these in vain:

```
 sed '/doadoodle/{x;/./p;x;h;d};x;/./!{x;b};x;H;$!d;x;s/doadoodle[^\n]*\n/&  "my append stuff here.Note its got newlines inside it"\n/' file
```

I tried something similar in `awk`, but it prints it after each "doadoodle". I'd like it after the last one.
Any clue how that'd be done?
Here is what I tried in `awk`:

```
tac file |  awk '{print} /^dooadoodle/&& !n {print "msg" ; n++}'
```

In spite of `tac` it will still append after the 1st occurrence of the string.
Can someone do it using just shell scripting and POSIX tools? Perl sounds a bit clumsy in the middle of a shell script.

TY Sam

Update to the question by BMW. File is in the following format:

```
Nohup Noodldo commands > filename 2>&1&
Nohup Noodldo commands > filename 2>&1&
Nohup Noodldo commands > filename 2>&1&
wait 
Nohup Noodldo commands > filename 2>&1&
Nohup Noodldo commands > filename 2>&1&
```

I will be nohupping these, so it's got to find the last instance of "Nohup" and stick the previous code,

```
   rc=$?
echo "$rc  is return code of last doadoodle" 
exit $rc
```

, in there.
The **2nd SED  solution** did work too - along with the AWK. **TY, folks**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724778/sed-return-last-occurrence-match-until-end-of-file - look up sed -i to insert with the given examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/doadoodle <parameters>/,$!b;//{x;//p};//!H;$!d;x;s//&\nrc=$?\necho "$rc  is return code of last doadoodle" \nexit $rc/' file
```

Print all lines as normal before the first pattern.

From the first pattern to the end of file:

If the current line contains the pattern, check the hold space for the pattern and if present print then delete the hold space (unless this happens to be the last line).

If the current line does not contain the pattern, append it to the hold space and delete it (unless it happens to be the last line).

When the current line is the last line swap to the hold space, insert the required string and print.

Answer (score 3):

If your file isnt too big then you can do this in two passes

```
### Store your text in a variable

$ new_stuff='rc=$?                                                                                             
echo "$rc  is return code of last doadoodle" 
exit $rc'
```

```
### Use that variable in awk one-liner

$ awk -v text="$new_stuff" '
  NR==FNR && /doadoodle/ { 
      last=NR; next 
  } 
  FNR==last { 
      print $0; printf "\n%s\n\n", text; next 
}1' file file
```

#### Output:

```
wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
doadoodle <parameters> 
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>

rc=$?
echo "$rc  is return code of last doadoodle" 
exit $rc

wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
```

Comment: this should work with the actual shell commands.I did a cursory test and all was well .TY

Answer (score 1):

One solution using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -ne '
    if (m/doadoodle/) {
        printf qq|%s|, join q||, splice @lines;
        $flag = 1;
    }
    push @lines, $_;
    END { 
        if ( $flag ) { 
            printf qq|%s\n%s\n%s|, shift @lines, <<EOF, join q||, splice @lines;
rc=$?
echo "$rc  is return code of last doadoodle" 
exit $rc
EOF
        }
        else {
            printf qq|%s|, join q||, splice @lines;
        }
    }
' infile
```

It saves processed lines in an array and flushes it to output when found a line that matches `doaddoodle`. In `END` section it checks if any `doadoodle` word was found (`$flag` checked) and inserts the text.

The results yields:

```
doadoodle <parameters> 
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>
wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
doadoodle <parameters>
doadoodle <parameters>

rc=0
echo "  is return code of last doadoodle" 
exit 

wait
some more stuff
yet some more stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed ':a;/\ndoadoodle/!{$s/doadoodle[^\n]*/&\n\nrc=$?\necho "$rc  is return code of last doadoodle" \nexit $rc\n/;N;ba}' file
```

Comment: This DOES work for the specific e.g.  above , but a slight change in file content will blind away the searching component.`ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah<br> if you can pl tell me what this SED is doing -I t'd be an easy change
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
wait
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
ndoadoodle blah
wait
` in the above case it wont find ndoadoodle. I am pretty sure - its just a minor change. TY again -now as in the past.

Comment: Can you please update the sample with slight change in your original question? The format in above comment are all in one line, I can't find out the difference.

Comment: Just did . Sorry they wont let ya add \n to comments. So all comments look like fresh or stale porridge.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another perl solution:

```
perl -0777pe 's/(.*doadoodle[^\n]+)/$1\n\nrc=\$?\necho "\$rc  is return code of last doadoodle"\nexit \$rc\n/s' /tmp/infile
```